# custom validate in shopware shipping address in confirm order page

Tags: shopware

How to add my custom validate in shopware shipping address in confirm order page .once if success that process to confirm order. Please explain how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just add additional field to address while address creation?

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'Shopware_Form_Builder' => ['onFormBuild', 1000]
    );
}

public function onFormBuild(\Enlight_Event_EventArgs $event)
{
    if (
        (   $event->getReference() !== \Shopware\Bundle\AccountBundle\Form\Account\PersonalFormType::class &&
            $event->getReference() !== \Shopware\Bundle\AccountBundle\Form\Account\AddressFormType::class  )
    ) {
        return;
    }

    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $builder */
    $builder = $event->getBuilder();

    $builder->get('additional')
        ->add('yourFieldName', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType::class, [
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank()
            ]
        ]);
}
```

If no, then you should subscribe to checkout postdispatch and check what you want:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PreDispatch_Frontend_Checkout' => 'onFrontendPreDispatchCheckout',
    );
}

/**
 * @param \Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs $args
 */
public function onFrontendPreDispatchCheckout(\Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs $args)
{
    /**@var $subject \Shopware_Controllers_Frontend_Checkout */
    $subject = $args->getSubject();
    $request = $subject->Request();
    $response = $subject->Response();
    $action = $request->getActionName();
    $view = $subject->View();

    if (!$request->isDispatched() || $response->isException() || 
    // only in case action is payment or confirm we should chcek it
    ($action != 'payment' && $action != 'confirm') ||
    !$view->hasTemplate()
    ) {
        return;
    }

    $validation = $this->thereWeCheckIt();
    if (
        $validation['message']
    ) {
                $subject->forward('index', 'account', 'frontend', array(
                    'errorVariable' => $validation['message'],
                ));
    }
}
```

Then you need also postDispatch account controller and show `errorVariable` to customer.

Comment: I need your help for this below question . Please review it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779822/shopware-zip-code-validation-in-confirm-order-page

Comment: How to get user shipping address details in onFrontendPreDispatchCheckout()

Comment: As case you can use: 
if(!empty(Shopware()->Session()->sUserId)){ 
        /** @var $customer \Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer */
        $customer = Shopware()->Models()->find('Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer', Shopware()->Session()->sUserId);
        if($customer instanceof \Shopware\Models\Customer\Customer){
             $customer->getShipping()
        }
}